# Django - How to pass onclick_attrib to Models in Admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django Admin interface, Whenever there is a change in a specific field of a Model, I just need to ask the confirmation using JS. I found that {{ onclick_attrib }} can achieve this. Can you please suggest from where we can pass this value? Is there any doc available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply include js file and do the stuff there.

Model definition:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  class Media:
    js = ('/js/my.js',)
```

And js (preview only):

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
    $("#id_field_name").change(function(){
      return confirm("???");
    });
  })
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is it possible to check while clicking on "SAVE" buttons?

Comment: Yes. It JavaScript question now :) However, it should become something like this http://dpaste.com/268354/

Comment: Thats correct. But, that code has some issues. The first one is field().val() -> filed.val(). How to get the old value of a field?

Comment: @Siva `field[0].defaultValue` is old value